# Set Content-MD5 in get request

Tags: c#, get, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code:

```
HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, uri);
byte[] md5 = {my hash};
message.Content.Headers.ContentMD5 = md5;
```

The problem is, `message.Content` is `null`.

The client I use is of type `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`

Now my question, how can I send a `HttpContent` in a `GET` request?

Answer (score 0):

My solution is, I created my own header. I planned to use the `Content-MD5` for caching, so I just created my own caching header.

Comment: I can't be sure, but it sounds like you just reinvented the Etag header.

Comment: I am confused; Content-MD5 is specific to request (it has been deprecated on response since '14 where this post is from) and ETag is specific to response. What do you wish to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

`Content-MD5` header should only be used when invoking either of the HTTP verbs; `PUT` or `POST`. No body is transferred from the client to the server on a `GET`.